# Components not displaying correctly when dynamically adding a JPanel to CardLayout

Tags: jpanel, jcomponent, cardlayout

I was hoping someone would be able to help me with the following problem.  I am creating a Java desktop application in which I have a JPanel topicPanel that contains two JPanels; topicButtonsPanel which contains the JButton createEntryButton and topicTabCardsPanel which implements the CardLayout.  When clicking the createEntryButton I am trying to dynamically create and add a new JPanel entryPanel that contains JTextlabels, JTextFIelds and JButtons.  The code used in the action performed method in the topicPanel class is:

```
private void createEntryButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                                  
    EntryPanel entryPanel = new EntryPanel();
    add(entryPanel);

    CardLayout cards = (CardLayout) topicTabCardsPanel.getLayout();
    cards.addLayoutComponent(entryPanel, "entryPanelCard");
    cards.show(topicTabCardsPanel, "entryPanelCard");
}
```

However, although the entryPanel is added to the topicPanel, the components within the topicPanel are not being displayed correctly.  Only the JTextFields appear to be displaying correctly, JLabels aren't displayed at all and JButtons only appear when hovered over?  I also have a JTextArea that doesn't display except the scroll bar when hovered over.

Here is the code for both the topicPanel and entryPanel classes:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

public class TopicTab extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private ProjectPanel projectPanel;

/**
 * Creates new form TopicTab
 */
public TopicTab(ProjectPanel projectPanel) {
    initComponents();
    this.projectPanel = projectPanel;
}

public TopicTab() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    TopicTab topicTab = new TopicTab();
    topicTab.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    topicButtonsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    createEntryButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    importEntryButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    topicTabCardsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    timelinePanel = new Timeline.TimelinePanel();

    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1275, 672));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1275, 672));
    setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    topicButtonsPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    createEntryButton.setText("Create Entry");
    createEntryButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createEntryButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    importEntryButton.setText("Import Entry");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout topicButtonsPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(topicButtonsPanel);
    topicButtonsPanel.setLayout(topicButtonsPanelLayout);
    topicButtonsPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        topicButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(topicButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(createEntryButton)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(importEntryButton)
            .addContainerGap(1071, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    topicButtonsPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        topicButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(topicButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(topicButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(createEntryButton)
                .addComponent(importEntryButton))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    add(topicButtonsPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    topicTabCardsPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    javax.swing.GroupLayout timelinePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(timelinePanel);
    timelinePanel.setLayout(timelinePanelLayout);
    timelinePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        timelinePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 1275, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    timelinePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        timelinePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 627, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    topicTabCardsPanel.add(timelinePanel, "card2");

    add(topicTabCardsPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void createEntryButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    EntryPanel entryPanel = new EntryPanel();
    add(entryPanel);

    CardLayout cards = (CardLayout) topicTabCardsPanel.getLayout();
    cards.addLayoutComponent(entryPanel, "entryPanelCard");
    cards.show(topicTabCardsPanel, "entryPanelCard");
}                                                 

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton createEntryButton;
private javax.swing.JButton importEntryButton;
private Timeline.TimelinePanel timelinePanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel topicButtonsPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel topicTabCardsPanel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}


public class EntryPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form EntryViewPanel
 */
public EntryPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialise the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    createEntryDetails = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    entryTitleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    entryDateLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    entryNotesLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    entryNotesTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    entryDayTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    entryTitleTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    entryMonthTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    entryYearTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    newEntryDateBackslashLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    newEntryDateBackslashLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    sourceDetailsTabbedPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    addSourcePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    addSourceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    buttonsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    createEntryButtonsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    createEntryButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    backButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    updateEntryButtonsPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    backButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    updateEntryButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 591));
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1275, 672));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1275, 672));
    setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Enter new entry details:");

    entryTitleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    entryTitleLabel.setText("Title:");

    entryDateLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    entryDateLabel.setText("Date (dd/mm/yy):");

    entryNotesLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    entryNotesLabel.setText("Notes:");

    entryNotesTextArea.setColumns(20);
    entryNotesTextArea.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    entryNotesTextArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(entryNotesTextArea);

    entryDayTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    entryTitleTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    entryMonthTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    entryYearTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

    newEntryDateBackslashLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    newEntryDateBackslashLabel.setText("/");

    newEntryDateBackslashLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    newEntryDateBackslashLabel1.setText("/");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout createEntryDetailsLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(createEntryDetails);
    createEntryDetails.setLayout(createEntryDetailsLayout);
    createEntryDetailsLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        createEntryDetailsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(entryTitleLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                    .addComponent(entryTitleTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 348, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                    .addComponent(entryDateLabel)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(entryDayTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(newEntryDateBackslashLabel)
                    .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                    .addComponent(entryMonthTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(newEntryDateBackslashLabel1)
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addComponent(entryYearTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 241, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(118, 118, 118)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 348, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(entryNotesLabel))
            .addContainerGap(437, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    createEntryDetailsLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        createEntryDetailsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(entryTitleLabel)
                .addComponent(entryTitleTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(entryDateLabel)
                .addComponent(entryDayTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(entryMonthTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(entryYearTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(newEntryDateBackslashLabel)
                .addComponent(newEntryDateBackslashLabel1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(createEntryDetailsLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(entryNotesLabel)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(0, 9, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    add(createEntryDetails, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    addSourceLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    addSourceLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addSourceLabel.setText("Click here to add a new Source");
    addSourceLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout addSourcePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(addSourcePanel);
    addSourcePanel.setLayout(addSourcePanelLayout);
    addSourcePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        addSourcePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(addSourcePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(addSourceLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    addSourcePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        addSourcePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(addSourcePanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(addSourceLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 437, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    addSourceLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("addSourcePanel");

    sourceDetailsTabbedPane.addTab("add source", addSourcePanel);

    add(sourceDetailsTabbedPane, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    sourceDetailsTabbedPane.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("sourceDetailsTabbedPane");

    buttonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));
    buttonsPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    createEntryButtonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));
    createEntryButtonsPanel.setName("createEntryButtonsPanel");
    createEntryButtonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));

    createEntryButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    createEntryButton.setText("Create");

    backButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    backButton.setText("Back");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout createEntryButtonsPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(createEntryButtonsPanel);
    createEntryButtonsPanel.setLayout(createEntryButtonsPanelLayout);
    createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(backButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(createEntryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(971, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(createEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(backButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(createEntryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    buttonsPanel.add(createEntryButtonsPanel, "createEntryButtonsPanel");

    updateEntryButtonsPanel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));
    updateEntryButtonsPanel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));
    updateEntryButtonsPanel.setName("updateEntryButtonsPanel");
    updateEntryButtonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1045, 68));

    backButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    backButton1.setText("Back");

    updateEntryButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    updateEntryButton.setText("Update");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(updateEntryButtonsPanel);
    updateEntryButtonsPanel.setLayout(updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout);
    updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(backButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(updateEntryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(971, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(updateEntryButtonsPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(backButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(updateEntryButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    buttonsPanel.add(updateEntryButtonsPanel, "updateEntryButtonsPanel");

    add(buttonsPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel addSourceLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel addSourcePanel;
private javax.swing.JButton backButton;
private javax.swing.JButton backButton1;
private javax.swing.JPanel buttonsPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton createEntryButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel createEntryButtonsPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel createEntryDetails;
private javax.swing.JLabel entryDateLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField entryDayTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField entryMonthTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel entryNotesLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextArea entryNotesTextArea;
private javax.swing.JLabel entryTitleLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField entryTitleTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField entryYearTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JLabel newEntryDateBackslashLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel newEntryDateBackslashLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane sourceDetailsTabbedPane;
private javax.swing.JButton updateEntryButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel updateEntryButtonsPanel;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 and Java: 1.7.0_04.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like I have this problem solved.  Instead of

```
add(entryPanel);
```

which was adding the entryPanel to the topicTab Panel, I should have been adding the entryPanel to the topicTabsCardPAnel with

```
topicTabCardsPanel.add(entryPanel);
```

Silly mistake!